# How to handle this MiKTeX update error?

Tags: miktex, miktex-update

After I installed MiKTeX 2.9, I got the following message in the MiKTeX update

> sorry, but something went wrong: the executed process did not succeed.
>   filename=c:\programfiles\MIKTEX2.9\miktex\bin\x64\initexml.exe,exitcode="1"

What could be the reason for the above situation?